# My BroadCastReceiver Called twice after reopen app

Tags: android, android-broadcast

i have created broadcast receiver for passing data between service to activity, when first time open app broadcast receiver called oknly once but when app open second time then broadcast receiver called twice 
-> code for pass data service to

```
    final Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(MainActivity.MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE, args);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

and here is code for handle response in activity and register receiver

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new MyWebRequestReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("broadCastName"));
```

handle its response

```
 public class MyWebRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "com.as400samplecode.intent.action.PROCESS_RESPONSE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getParcelableExtra(AutoOpenAppService.BUNDLE1);
        String mainUrl = bundle.getString(MAINURL);
        Boolean wvVisible = bundle.getBoolean(WVBOOLEAN);
        Bundle args = intent.getParcelableExtra(AutoOpenAppService.BUNDLE);
        ArrayList<? extends UrlTimeModel> list = args.getParcelableArrayList(LIST);
        Long TimeOut = args.getLong(TIMEOUT);

        if (mainUrl != null) {
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                setWebView(mainUrl);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "VISIBLE : " + wvVisible);

        if (wvVisible) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            if (alert != null) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        assert list != null;
        if (list.size() < 0) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    alert.dismiss();
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    MainActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            }, TimeOut);
        }
        LoadSubURl((ArrayList<UrlTimeModel>) list, TimeOut);
    }
}
```

unregister in onstop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
        timerTask = null;
    }
    // TODO: 20/12/17 Call Hide Icon Method
    HideIconMethod();

    if (bound) {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        bound = false;
    }
    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: try `onDestroy()` instead of `onStop()`

Comment: i have solved problem , problem another place, but thanks for reply @CagriYalcin , i have called api twice